# 403 error on passing parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following function in a php file :

```
function bc_output($vars) {
    switch($_GET['a']){
        case 'addip':
            bc_add_licenses($vars, trim($_GET['current_ip']));
        break;
        case 'addiprequest':
            if(isset($_POST['submitaddip'])) {
                display_guidance_text();
                bc_add_licenses_request($vars, $_POST);
            } else {
                display_guidance_text();
                bc_get_licenses($vars, '4');
            }
        break;
        default:
            display_guidance_text();
            bc_get_licenses($vars);
        break;
    }
}
```

Now when i go to url such as http://website.com/addon.php?module=b&a=addip it works fine, although for second case i.e http://website.com/addon.php?module=b&a=addiprequest browser throws 403 error..

Can anyone guide me where to proceed from here, i have echoed etc in the function but always 403 error.

Please comment if you need more info.

Comment: The browser doesn't give you the error, the server does. Check the logs.

Comment: In you php can you echo the `$_GET` var? It's probably not making it that far, so does your htaccess code look like please?

Comment: when i echo $_GET va in above function even then i get 403 error, strange is this is working in other case i.e addip only addiprequest is not working

Comment: First check your Apache error.log and show the reason of this 403 error.